# How can I access an uploaded file in universal-newline mode?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am working with a file uploaded using Django's `forms.FileField`. This returns an object of type `InMemoryUploadedFile`.

I need to access this file in universal-newline mode. Any ideas on how to do this without saving and then reopening the file?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are using Python 2.6 or higher, you can use the `io.StringIO` class after having read your file into memory (using the read() method). Example:

```
>>> import io
>>> s = u"a\r\nb\nc\rd"
>>> sio = io.StringIO(s, newline=None)
>>> sio.readlines()
[u'a\n', u'b\n', u'c\n', u'd']
```

To actually use this in your django view, you may need to convert the input file data to unicode:

```
stream = io.StringIO(unicode(request.FILES['foo'].read()), newline=None)
```

Comment: This works great. I use it along with csv.DictReader in my django view. `reader = csv.DictReader(stream)` then `for row in reader: #import each row` Any thoughts on what this will do with memory usage? I'm on a 'budget' :) I know I should probably just save the file in a temp location but am curious if for the time being I need to do any garbage-like clean up?

Comment: This work aslong as the original file can be encode as utf-8, for non utf-8 file it raise error :(