# Not able to parse a .csv file uploaded using Flask

Tags: python, csv, flask

I am trying to upload a CSV file, work on it to produce results, and write back (download) a new CSV file containing the result.
I am very new to Flask and I am not able to get a "proper" `csv.reader` object to iterate and work upon.
Here is the code so far,

```
__author__ = 'shivendra'
from flask import Flask, make_response, request
import csv

app = Flask(__name__)

def transform(text_file_contents):
    return text_file_contents.replace("=", ",")


@app.route('/')
def form():
    return """
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1>Transform a file demo</h1>

                <form action="/transform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="data_file" />
                    <input type="submit" />
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
    """

@app.route('/transform', methods=["POST"])
def transform_view():
    file = request.files['data_file']
    if not file:
        return "No file"

    file_contents = file.stream.read().decode("utf-8")
    csv_input = csv.reader(file_contents)
    print(file_contents)
    print(type(file_contents))
    print(csv_input)
    for row in csv_input:
        print(row)

    result = transform(file_contents)

    response = make_response(result)
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=result.csv"
    return response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001, debug=True)
```

The terminal output being

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Oct/2015 02:51:53] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Oct/2015 02:51:59] "POST /transform HTTP/1.1" 200 -
4,5,6
<class 'str'>
<_csv.reader object at 0x105149438>
['1']
['', '']
['2']
['', '']
['3']
[]
['4']
['', '']
['5']
['', '']
['6']
```

Whereas the file I read is

[image]

What am I doing wrong to not get 2 lists representing 2 rows when I iterate the csv.reader object?

Comment: Could you show what your csv file looks like in a text format and not in a spreadsheet program. Also what spreadsheet program are you using to generate the csv (if any). And one more thing, why is it necessary to replace `=` with `,`? Most csv dialects don't use equal signs.

Comment: @iLoveTux Replacing `=` with `,` is completely unnecessary. Transform is a dummy function for now. But I couldn't reach till there as I am stuck at the csv reading part.

Comment: Added the text file image of the csv.

Comment: Formatting in the comments on this site is strange. Is that a newline between 3 and 4? By the results of iterating through your csv it would appear that there is a carriage return `\r` or a newline `\n` after each number, but if thats not the case, I would need an actual copy of the csv file to play around with in order to figure it out

Comment: Yes, it is strange. I uploaded the file at https://www.dropbox.com/s/xmgn8n3o9leor12/blog1.csv?dl=0

Comment: Don't use screenshots of files, paste the text instead.

Comment: @nathancahill I did that , but the comment section on SO seems to remove most of the formatting etc.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

OK, so there is one major problem with your script, `csv.reader` as noted [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) expects a file object or at least an object which supports the iterator protocol. You are passing a `str` which does implement the iterator protocol, but instead of iterating through the lines, it iterates through the characters. This is why you have the output you do.

First, it gives a singe character `1` which the `csv.reader` sees as a line with one field. After that the `str` gives another single character `,` which the `csv.reader` sees as a line with two empty fields (since the comma is the field seperator). It goes on like that throughout the `str` until it's exhausted.

The solution (or at least one solution) is to turn the `str` into a file-like object. I tried using the stream provided by `flask.request.files["name"]`, but that doesn't iterate through the lines. Next, I tried using a `cStringIO.StringIO` and that seemed to have a similar issue. I ended up at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875956/how-can-i-access-an-uploaded-file-in-universal-newline-mode) question which suggested an `io.StringIO` object in universal newlines mode which worked. I ended up with the following working code (perhaps it could be better):

```
__author__ = 'shivendra'
from flask import Flask, make_response, request
import io
import csv

app = Flask(__name__)

def transform(text_file_contents):
    return text_file_contents.replace("=", ",")


@app.route('/')
def form():
    return """
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1>Transform a file demo</h1>

                <form action="/transform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="data_file" />
                    <input type="submit" />
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
    """

@app.route('/transform', methods=["POST"])
def transform_view():
    f = request.files['data_file']
    if not f:
        return "No file"

    stream = io.StringIO(f.stream.read().decode("UTF8"), newline=None)
    csv_input = csv.reader(stream)
    #print("file contents: ", file_contents)
    #print(type(file_contents))
    print(csv_input)
    for row in csv_input:
        print(row)

    stream.seek(0)
    result = transform(stream.read())

    response = make_response(result)
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=result.csv"
    return response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001, debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't tell you how much I appreciate your effort. It worked.  Not only you solved my problem, you helped me understand each line of the code properly. You are awesome.

Comment: Yup, thank you for your detailed response. Not easy to find a proper response on the web. You did it ;)

Answer (score 8):

Important note: This answer is relevant only for platforms where [SpooledTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile) is available.

Further to [iLuveTux answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33071581/4188683), you can save the redundant `read()` call by replacing the following string-based stream creation:

```
stream = io.StringIO(f.stream.read().decode("UTF8"), newline=None)
```

with:

```
stream = io.TextIOWrapper(f.stream._file, "UTF8", newline=None)
```

Example:

```
stream = io.TextIOWrapper(f.stream._file, "UTF8", newline=None)
csv_input = csv.reader(stream)
print(csv_input)
for row in csv_input:
    print(row)
```

---

Further information:

Werkzeug default stream for form data parser is [SpooledTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile) (as of [1.0.1](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/1.0.1/src/werkzeug/formparser.py#L53)), from which you can obtain the underlying buffer using its `_file` memeber.

Comment: I just learned something. Thank you!