# Opening csv file in Python: builtins. AttributeError AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'file'

Tags: python, csv, flask

further to my earlier question, on how to open an csv file in Python, I am still not successful in doing so and going from error to error.

My Python code is as follows:

```
@app.route("/admin", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def admin():
"""Configure Admin Screen"""
# if user reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
if request.method == "POST":

    # load csv file with portfolio data
    csvfile = TextIOWrapper(request.files['portfolios'].file, encoding=request.encoding)
    portfolios = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

    # load csv file in dictionary
    for row in portfolios:
        print(row['first_name'], row['last_name'])
else:
    return render_template("admin.html")
```

My flask/html code is as follows:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

`{% block title %}
    Admin
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
<h2>Admin Console</h2>
<h3> Upload Portfolio Data</h2>
<form action="{{ url_for('admin') }}" method="post" enctype=multipart/form-
data>
 <fieldset>
    <label class="control-label">Select Portfolio Upload File</label>
    <input id="input-1" type="file" class="file" name="portfolios">
    <h3>Upload Security Lists</h2>
    <label class="control-label">Select Security Upload File</label>
    <input id="input-1" type="file" class="file" name="securities">
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value = "upload">Upload</button>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Initially, I literally followed the example from the Python documentation:
    import csv
    with open('names.csv') as csvfile:
      reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
      for row in reader:
         print(row['first_name'], row['last_name'])

this didnt work as it gave a type error ([see my earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43980448/opening-csv-file-in-python-using-flask/43984679?noredirect=1#comment75036242_43984679))

I then removed, as suggested, the "open", which resulted in another error. I then removed the whole with block, which again resulted in an error. Now, the above code is what I am now, and its generating the following error:

builtins.AttributeError
AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'file'

Anyone who can help my csv import nightmare to end?? Txs!!

Comment: have you just tried `csvfile = TextIOWrapper(request.files['portfolios'], encoding=request.encoding)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`io.TextIOWrapper` takes a `io.BytesIO` object all right.

You're (almost) passing it, except that you're adding a `.file` (why??), which is not a field of the `io.BytesIO` class (`request.files['portfolios']` is a `io.BytesIO` object already)

Just do:

```
csvfile = TextIOWrapper(request.files['portfolios'], encoding=request.encoding)
```

Comment: Hmmmmm, if I do that, I get an AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'encoding'.... :(

Comment: it means that you already had that issue. I didn't change the type of `request`. Try to omit the "encoding" parameter.