# read file posted to pyramid web app as text

Tags: postman, python-3.6, pyramid

I have a web app build with pyramid. One of the endpoints `/foo` is connected to the method `foo(request)`:

```
def foo(request):
    file = request.POST['my_file'].file
    ...do stuff with file...
```

I then send a file to the endpoint using postman. The problem is, the file is opened as a `BufferedRandom` in binary mode, but I need to manipulate the file in text mode. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer here: [Not able to parse a .csv file uploaded using Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33070395/not-able-to-parse-a-csv-file-uploaded-using-flask/33071581#33071581)

In my case I added

```
stream = io.StringIO(file.read().decode("utf8"), newline=None)
```

and was able to manipulate `stream`