# Flask request csv

Tags: python, flask, request

I have a csv file, which I need to post on my server, convert it to json and send it back. With JSON, you can simply do **request.json(Force=True)**, however I am not sure how to make flask to read my csv.

So far I have this:

```
@application.route('/postcsv', methods=['POST'])
def csv_view():
    content = request.files(force=True)

    stream = io.StringIO(content.stream.read().decode("UTF-8"), newline = None)
    csv_input = csv.reader(stream)
    print(csv_input)
    return csv_input


if __name__ == '__main__':
application.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

The error I am getting is `TypeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' object is not callable`. I think my approach overall is wrong but I am not sure

Comment: I assume the error come from the following line: `content = request.files(force=True)`. Instead, you should use `content = request.files['parameter_name']`. There is more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015550/read-file-data-without-saving-it-in-flask)

Comment: Share the stacktrace please

Comment: This also mixes the `request.json` attribute with the `request.get_json()` method which does permit an optional `force=True` keyword parameter for accepting form data which doesn't have the expected `application/json` content type. I'm at loss as to what the OP might perceive to be the expected content type for `files`.

Answer (score 1):

You got this error because [`request.files`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request.files) is not a function and thus can't be called.

Instead, you should use `request.files[<KEY>]`. See: [Not able to parse a .csv file uploaded using Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33070395/not-able-to-parse-a-csv-file-uploaded-using-flask)